# Issue with ToListAsync and CancelationToken

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

dbContext is provided via dependency injection to ASP.NET Core service class. I would like to leverage async processing and cancelation token. One of the time-consuming database calls retrieves a set of records and materializes them using ToListAsync method as below. I am passing cancelation token to ToListAsync method.

```
await _dbContext.ViewMappings.Where(e => e.Level == Level && e.Code.ToString() == Code).Select(c => new
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Label = c.Label,
                parentId = c.ParentId,
                parentLabel = c.ParentLabel
            }).ToListAsync(token);

//check for cancel request
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

When I navigate away from the page, I am getting below error message:
An error occurred using the connection to database 'XXX' on server 'YYY'.

Error message and Stack trace:

```
An error occurred using the connection to database 'XXX' on server 'YYY'
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.RelationalConnectionDiagnosticsLogger.ConnectionErrorAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, Exception exception, DateTimeOffset startTime, TimeSpan duration, Boolean logErrorAsDebug, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()    at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.ThrowLoggingError(List`1 exceptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Define>g__Log|0(ILogger logger, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.RelationalConnectionDiagnosticsLogger.ConnectionErrorAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, Exception exception, DateTimeOffset startTime, TimeSpan duration, Boolean logErrorAsDebug, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
```

I have used async/await pattern along with cancelationtoken in other places and they work as expected. It is only when using ToListAsync method, I face this error.

When I looked at the .NET Core's implementation of ToListAsync method, this is what I see:

```
public static async Task<List<TSource>> ToListAsync<TSource>(
            this IQueryable<TSource> source,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var list = new List<TSource>();
            await foreach (var element in source.AsAsyncEnumerable().WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
            {
                list.Add(element);
            }

            return list;
        }
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? I am suspecting that the cancel event is raised while the task is processing, so the database connection was closed/disposed as expected but the request dealing with ToListAsync did not listen to the cancel event and is continuing to process the results but cannot continue because the database connection is not available? Is that what is going on?

**UPDATE**

I moved things around and wrapped the async call with try/catch block. To my surprise I am able to catch the TaskCanceledException now.

If I have few synchronous steps after the async call and if task canceled exception is raised, will the synchronous steps run irrespective? I thought they wouldn't but the output I am seeing is indicating otherwise. Could someone please clarify?

```
try
{
var results = await _dbContext.ViewMappings.Where(e => e.Level == Level && e.Code.ToString() == Code).Select(c => new
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Label = c.Label,
                parentId = c.ParentId,
                parentLabel = c.ParentLabel
            }).ToListAsync(token);

//check for cancel request
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

  foreach(var result in results)
  {
     Debug.WriteLine("processing results");
  }
}
```

When the task is canceled, I am still seeing the output "processing results". Can someone please point out my mistake? Do I need to move the async call to its own method?

Comment: What error? Isn't it cancellationexception? Which you could catch and swallow?

Comment: *"When I navigate away from the page, I am getting below error message"* -- What it the type of the `Exception`, and which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias and Selvin It is of type System.AggregateException. It does not tell the line number but I am guessing it is the ToListAsync operation. I am unable to catch it, infact, if I use try/catch block with generic Exception parameter, it never stops at the catch breakpoint.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias and Selvin - I added stack trace to my original post.

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing an `await ` somewhere otherwise you wouldn't get `AggregateException`. But if you use the debugger, it will stop at the exception and you can see the details. Or log it to a file. We need to see the inner exception details

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface. I added an update to my orignal post. I am able to catch the exception now! I do have a question though. If I have few synchronous steps after the async call and if task canceled exception is raised, will the synchronous steps run irrespective? I thought they wouldn't but the output I am seeing is indicating otherwise. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: Biostat you could consider posting this question as a new question.

Comment: No it won't run. There is something odd going on here: either the exception is not happening where you think it is, or you are doing something weird with tasks. Can we see how you call this code, can we see the rest of the function?